# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. - ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to set up a HTTP-get request on my ionic application but i keep getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.wikicode.co.uk/announcement?
date=value2&message=value3&name=value1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100'     
is therefore not allowed access.
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong. I've tried googling it but didn't have much luck.

Here's my code:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Announcement</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="Announcement">
    <ion-view view-title="Announcements">
      <ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
          <h1 class="title">Announcement</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
         <br>
         <br>
         <br>
        <ionic-content ng-controller="Controller">
          <button class="button" ng-click="getData()">Do something</button>
          <br>
         name: {{name}} {{date}} {{message}}
          </ionic-content>
      </ion-pane>
    </ion-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('announcementsCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('chatsCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('photosCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('profilesCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get("http://www.wikicode.co.uk/announcement", { params: { "name": "value1", "date": "value2", "message": "value3"} })
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.name = data.name;
                $scope.date = data.date;
                $scope.message = data.message;
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                alert("ERROR");
            });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with RESTful APIs that do not support CORS headers. You can work around this during development by using the proxy option in the Ionic CLI. I wrote a tutorial about this on my site http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-issues-revisited/.

The big thing to remember is this only works for building the app. It does not solve the root of the problem. You have two options 1) get wikicode.co.uk to support CORS headers or 2) create another REST API that proxies to the real API but adds CORS headers. There are lots of ways to do #2, but here is how to build a simple Node server that does this. http://chafey.blogspot.com/2014/09/working-around-cors.html